# Attach a database using MDF file that is Read-only and without LDF file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, mdf, ldf

I want to attach a DB to SQL Server. I have the mdf files for it but those are in read-only state. Also the LDF file is not present. I use the following command to attach the DB.

```
Create database TrackData on (Filename = N'F:\Data\Bill_Data.mdf') FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
```

but i get the following error.

```
Msg 3415, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Database 'Bill_Data' cannot be upgraded because it is read-only or has read-only files. Make the database or files writeable, and rerun recovery.
Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Could not open new database 'Bill_Data'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
```

I know that it might not be possible to recover the Database in this case as MDF file is in read-only state. Also I do not have a backup of database. But still expecting any wild ideas that could help.

Comment: There would appear to be [no way around not using the LDF file](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63255/database-cannot-be-upgraded-because-it-is-read-only-or-has-read-only-files-make).  Maybe you can get a hold of it somehow.

Comment: @user2864740 to the same server version

Comment: to attach a MDF file without a LDF you use `sp_attach_db`. What do you mean read only? Do you mean the files read only bit is flagged? Just unflag it first

Comment: Visit this link : <https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63255/database-cannot-be-upgraded-because-it-is-read-only-or-has-read-only-files-make> Hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

Paste your .mdf file and ldf file in this directory - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SS2012\MSSQL\DATA
and make sure that the folder in which your .mdf file resides is not read only.
please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061137/4882409) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22243594/4882409).