# project after install database readonly how to remove it

Tags: vb.net

My database is read-only don't let me edit it in sql-server

here is a pic u can check it

[image]

trying to edit it via sql server receive this message

The Database `C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\PC\FOLDER2\DATABASE1.MDF`  is not accessible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [database attached is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054997/database-attached-is-read-only)

Comment: what should i do

Comment: Read the answers in the link above and try if something helps you? I guess [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055051/2967965) could help...